# NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/RestAssured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I have following problem with test execute from .bat file. I execute my test from .bat file.

```
set projectPath=D:\git\content-generator-tests
cd %projectPath%
set classpath=%projectPath%\target\classes;%projectPath%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectPath%\dev.xml
pause
```

I'm not sure that above .bat file is correct.

After execute my test from .bat file I received

```
FAILED: testGetParagraphs("http://192.168.0.139:8880/paragraphs", "inputText", "tescik tescik")
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/RestAssured
        at com.content.generator.pages.Paragraphs.getParagraph(Paragraphs.java:112)
        at com.content.generator.tests.ParagraphsApiControllerTests.testGetParagraphs(ParagraphsApiControllerTests.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
        at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
        at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
        at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:41)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:443)
        at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.RestAssured
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 25 more
```

However when I'm running my test from dev.xml in Intellij everything is OK and I received correct result. From .bat file I got different result. Can someone help?

Comment: Where do you tell your main class about class path?          
try     "

java –classpath %classpath%  org.testng.TestNG %projectPath%\dev.xml"

Comment: I try with this and another error in command line.
D:\git\content-generator-tests>java ÔÇôclasspath D:\git\content-generator-tests\target\classes;D:\git\content-generator-tests\lib\* org.testng.TestNG D:\git\content-generator-tests\dev.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class ÔÇôclasspath

Comment: Are you using build tools like maven/gradle to add dependencies to your project? Or adding it manually in Intellij ?

Comment: Yes I have pom.xml with dependencies.

Comment: Try setting your Java classpath in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file by using the Class-Path attribute. 

Eg : 

Main-Class: org.testng.TestNG


         
Class-Path: lib/*.jar

Comment: Where is META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223585/discussion-between-goney225-and-mahesh-loya).

Comment: Any help from someone?